# Metro: 2033 Crashes Immediately After Opening

Tags: technical-issues, metro-2033

Metro 2033 crashes to desktop immediately after opening sometimes showing the 4A Games Sting for a moment, but then showing a "Metro 2033 has stopped responding" dialog.

This happens on my Windows 8.1 rig running:

- AMD FX-8150 @ 4.20GHz
- 16GB of RAM
- 2x Nvidia GTX 660 through SLI

Things I've tried:

- Verifying the Integrity of the Game Caching through Steam
- Updated Nvidia Drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of the Nvidia PhysX software from their downloads page.  Regardless of if you have a AMD/ATI or Nvidia card, Metro 2033 needs the PhysX package.

[Download the NVIDIA PhysX System Software here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_system_software.html)